# Why tupleWritable become empty when passed to recuder

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

I have a map(Object key,Text value,Context context) , put a tupleWritable in the context with context.write(). and In the reduce(Text key,Iterable values,Context context),I read the tupleWritable ,but it's empty.
   below is my code.That confused me ,any help will be appreciated.

```
package boc.competition.team1;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.join.TupleWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.MultipleInputs;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;;

public class App 
{
    public static class SCSTransMap extends Mapper<Object,Text,Text,TupleWritable>{
        private Text name = new Text();

        @Override
        public void map(Object key,Text value,Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException{
                IntWritable i = new IntWritable(1);
                TupleWritable result = new TupleWritable(new IntWritable[] { i, new IntWritable(3)});
                System.out.println(result.get(0)+"====="+result.get(1));
//------here print the right value  1=====3
                context.write(name, result);
            }
        }
    }
    public static class reducer extends Reducer<Text,TupleWritable,Text,Text>{
        @Override
        public void reduce(Text key,Iterable<TupleWritable> values,Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException{

            for(TupleWritable tuple:values) {
                System.out.println(tuple.get(0)+"====="+tuple.get(1));
// and here print 0=======0
            }

        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf,"team1Job");
        job.setJarByClass(App.class);
        job.setReducerClass(reducer.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(TupleWritable.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path("C:\\Program Files\\PuTTY\\data\\scs\\Scs_Journal.csv"), TextInputFormat.class,SCSTransMap.class);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(OUT_PATH));

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ben Watson,there is other code to do with the variable"name".it is less imporant to the issue,so i didn't post them

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to delete my comment. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

I use a user define writable class instead of tupleWritable class to pass the value from map to reduce
here is user define writtable

```
package boc.competition.team1;

import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;

public class IntPairWritable implements Writable {
        private IntWritable value1;
        private IntWritable value2;

        public IntPairWritable() {
            value1 = new IntWritable();
            value2 = new IntWritable();
        }

        public IntPairWritable(int value1, int value2) {
            this.value1 = new IntWritable(value1);
            this.value2 = new IntWritable(value2);
        }

        public int getInt1() {
            return value1.get();
        }

        public int getInt2() {
            return value2.get();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return value1.toString()+" "+value2.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
            value1.readFields(in);
            value2.readFields(in);
        }

        @Override
        public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
            value1.write(out);
            value2.write(out);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the `TupleWritable.java` source file:

```java
 * This is *not* a general-purpose tuple type. In almost all cases, users are
 * encouraged to implement their own serializable types, which can perform
 * better validation and provide more efficient encodings than this class is
 * capable. TupleWritable relies on the join framework for type safety and
 * assumes its instances will rarely be persisted, assumptions not only
 * incompatible with, but contrary to the general case.
```

Also see the answer from Chris Douglas-3 [here](http://hadoop.6.n7.nabble.com/Passing-TupleWritable-between-map-and-reduce-td2729.html):

> You need access to TupleWritable::setWritten(int). If you want to use
>   TupleWritable outside the join package, then you need to make this
>   (and probably related methods, like clearWritten(int)) public and
>   recompile.

It seems safe to say that `TupleWritable` is not meant to be a publicly used class for MapReduce jobs.